# How to read image from table and on button click show it full size, inside popup window?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**1. Explaination**

I have a list of images/picture that are listen inside a page through a table.
Each image/picture has a unique name and is successfully shown in the table.

What i want is to view the one i choose, in full screen, inside a popup window, on button click.

**2. Question**

How can i show the picture inside a popup window?

**3. The frontend code**

// The table

```
  <table id="table1" class="border-0"
                   style="width: 100%;text-align: left;">
                <thead class="border-0">
                    <tr class="text-dark">                          
                        <th style="width:10%;">
                            Data
                        </th>                           
                        <th style="width:80%;">
                            Explaination
                        </th>                            
                        <th style="width:1%;text-align:right;">
                            Image                             
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.ImgList)
                {
                    <tr class="border-bottom">                               
                        <td>                             
                            @item.ImgDate.ToShortDateString()
                        </td>                              
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text)
                        </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark font-weight-bold border-0"
                                   data-id="@item.MyImgId" data-imgid="@(item.MyImgId)" data-toggle="modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" style="min-width:80px;">
                                    <img src="~/grafi/@(item.MyImgId + ".png")" height="50" alt="image" id="myImg" />
                                </a>                                                                     
                            </td>                           
                    </tr>
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

//The popup modal

```
<!-- The Modal -->
                                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                    <img id="img01" style="height:100vh" />
                                </div>
```

//The scripts

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var img = document.getElementById("myImg");

var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

img.onclick = function(){

  modal.style.display = "block";

  modalImg.src = this.src;

  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;

}


var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: I see a lot of code in your question. What is the actual problem you are having with achieving what you want? There are many examples doing similar things. Did you search for existing examples?

Comment: It does not show the picture inside the popup. The nearest thing i found, but that does not get the image from a table, is this:    https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just moved it in a table. Seems to work fine:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
console.log(modal);
// get the modal image
var caption = document.getElementById("modalImg");
// get the caption span
var caption = document.getElementById("caption");
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var close = document.getElementById("close");
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
close.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
for (let image of images) {
  image.onclick = function(event) {
    image = event.target;
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = image.src;
    caption.innertext = image.alt;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .image {
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .image:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
    /* The Modal (background) */
    
    .modal {
      display: none;
      /* Hidden by default */
      position: fixed;
      /* Stay in place */
      z-index: 1;
      /* Sit on top */
      padding-top: 100px;
      /* Location of the box */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      /* Full width */
      height: 100%;
      /* Full height */
      overflow: auto;
      /* Enable scroll if needed */
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      /* Black w/ opacity */
    }
    /* Modal Content (image) */
    
    .modal-content {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
    }
    /* Caption of Modal Image */
    
    #caption {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #ccc;
      padding: 10px 0;
      height: 150px;
    }
    /* Add Animation */
    
    .modal-content,
    #caption {
      -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
      animation-name: zoom;
      animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
      from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0)
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1)
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes zoom {
      from {
        transform: scale(0)
      }
      to {
        transform: scale(1)
      }
    }
    /* The Close Button */
    
    .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 35px;
      color: #f1f1f1;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #bbb;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Image Modal</h2>
  <p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
  <p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>


  <table id="table1" class="border-0" style="width: 100%;text-align: left;">
    <thead class="border-0">
      <tr class="text-dark">
        <th style="width:10%;">
          Data
        </th>
        <th style="width:80%;">
          Explaination
        </th>
        <th style="width:1%;text-align:right;">
          Image
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="border-bottom">
        <td>
          image
        </td>
        <td>
          some text
        </td>
        <td>
          <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border-bottom">
        <td>
          image
        </td>
        <td>
          some text
        </td>
        <td>
          <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span id="close" class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works but only for the first row. How can this be done to open the n-th row?

Comment: @Fillo updated the example. This is just a simple example, I suggest you look into more examples to learn how to do such things yourself.

Comment: I was already experimenting on finding a solution, but had not found a solution yet. Thank you.